# CSS: Left align block, but center contents in BS4

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a countdown timer on my site, which requires it's text content to be aligned centrally. I however would like to place the countdown timer in a container itself, and align the whole of the timer to the left of the container. Here is my current code:

https://codepen.io/Darlton29/pen/OJNzXEB

I would like the timer itself to be aligned to the left, however no matter what I try I cannot seem to get it to work, I have tried wrapping it in another container like so:

```
      <div class="container">
        <div class="countdown">
          <ul>
            <li><span id="days"></span>days</li>
            <li><span id="hours"></span>Hours</li>
            <li><span id="minutes"></span>Minutes</li>
            <li><span id="seconds"></span>Seconds</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

But this didn't work.

CSS:

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

li span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 4.5rem;
}

.countdown {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: You just need change your `.countdown` CSS from `text-align:center` to `text-align:left`!

Comment: Also, FYI you should include the relevant code in the question itself so it meets Stack Overflow guidelines. A codepen link is ok as long as the code is added here too :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll remember that for next time. Doing the above however doesn't work. The answer below seems to do the trick.

Comment: It does exactly the same as the answer below- except directly in the CSS instead of adding another class to override your CSS :) Then you just need to adjust padding to suit. I'd suggest you [edit] this question to include the code - even if you have answer, it could still get downvoted for not having the required information.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `flex`:

```js
const second = 1000,
  minute = second * 60,
  hour = minute * 60,
  day = hour * 24;

let countDown = new Date('Sep 30, 2020 00:00:00').getTime(),
  x = setInterval(function() {

    let now = new Date().getTime(),
      distance = countDown - now;

    document.getElementById('days').innerText = Math.floor(distance / (day)),
      document.getElementById('hours').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (day)) / (hour)),
      document.getElementById('minutes').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (hour)) / (minute)),
      document.getElementById('seconds').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (minute)) / second);

    //do something later when date is reached
    //if (distance < 0) {
    //  clearInterval(x);
    //  'IT'S MY BIRTHDAY!;
    //}

  }, second)
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.countdown {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.countdown ul li span {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<section style="background-color: pink; color: white;">
  <div class="container-fluid mt-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <h1>BIRTHDAY COUNTDOWN</h1>
        <h2>Countdown to my birthday:</h2>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="countdown">
            <ul>
              <li><span id="days"></span>days</li>
              <li><span id="hours"></span>Hours</li>
              <li><span id="minutes"></span>Minutes</li>
              <li><span id="seconds"></span>Seconds</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Codepen screenshot.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in codepen: https://codepen.io/Darlton29/pen/OJNzXEB

Comment: Technically it should work! what about in the app? I see it is taking auto `margin` between the div.

Comment: @S.Stevens add `margin:0;` to `.container{...}` and let me know. It worked for me even for codepen.

Comment: This did move it more to the left, however there is still quite a large gap: https://codepen.io/Darlton29/pen/OJNzXEB

Comment: I thought you want in that way, so you need the numbers to in the same alignment with `h1`?

Comment: I do, however this is not what is displaying in the above codepen, there is still a large gap between the start of the h1 and the first number,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221045/discussion-between-manjuboyz-and-s-stevens).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following modifications

```
<section style="background-color: pink; color: white;"> 
  <div class="container-fluid mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <h1>BIRTHDAY COUNTDOWN</h1>
          <h2>Countdown to my birthday:</h2>
          <div class="container ml-0">
            <div class="countdown text-left">
              <ul class="pl-0">
                <li><span id="days"></span>days</li>
                <li><span id="hours"></span>Hours</li>
                <li><span id="minutes"></span>Minutes</li>
                <li><span id="seconds"></span>Seconds</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

li span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 4.5rem;
}

.countdown {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem 0.5rem 0; 
  text-align: center;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/kostasx/pen/RwaxRXY?editors=1100)

Comment: This doesn't quite work, as the text below the timer is no longer centered below each individual number, this is the issue I was having before and the same result can be achieved by simply changing .countdown CSS from text-align:center to text-align:left, it's a minor but very important difference.